# operator.itemgetter or lambda

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I was curious if there was any indication of which of `operator.itemgetter(0)` or `lambda x:x[0]` is better to use, specifically in `sorted()` as the `key` keyword argument as that's the use that springs to mind first. Are there any known performance differences? Are there any PEP related preferences or guidance on the matter?

Comment: I would advise to use `operator.itemgetter(0)`

Comment: even over the standard readability?  isn't this sort of performance-based decision making premature optimization?

Comment: @hexparrot it's such a small code difference, and I don't think readability is better one way or the other. I'm just wondering for the sake of integrating whichever is "better" into my regular lexicon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should I use operator.itemgetter(x) instead of \[x\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287207/why-should-i-use-operator-itemgetterx-instead-of-x)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to my benchmark on a list of 1000 tuples, using `itemgetter` is almost twice as quick as the plain `lambda` method. The following is my code:

```
In [1]: a = list(range(1000))

In [2]: b = list(range(1000))

In [3]: import random

In [4]: random.shuffle(a)

In [5]: random.shuffle(b)

In [6]: c = list(zip(a, b))

In [7]: %timeit c.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
81.4 µs ± 433 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [8]: random.shuffle(c)

In [9]: from operator import itemgetter

In [10]: %timeit c.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
47 µs ± 202 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

I have also tested the performance (run time in µs) of this two method for various list size.

```
+-----------+--------+------------+
| List size | lambda | itemgetter |
+-----------+--------+------------+
| 100       | 8.19   | 5.09       |
+-----------+--------+------------+
| 1000      | 81.4   | 47         |
+-----------+--------+------------+
| 10000     | 855    | 498        |
+-----------+--------+------------+
| 100000    | 14600  | 10100      |
+-----------+--------+------------+
| 1000000   | 172000 | 131000     |
+-----------+--------+------------+
```

[image]

(The code producing the above image can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jdhao/5569afa7efc13abf75a5baf18e7c29d6))

Combined with the conciseness to select multiple elements from a list, `itemgetter` is clearly the winner to use in sort method.

Answer (score 47):

The performance of itemgetter is slightly better:

```
>>> f1 = lambda: sorted(w, key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> f2 = lambda: sorted(w, key=itemgetter(1))
>>> timeit(f1)
21.33667682500527
>>> timeit(f2)
16.99106214600033
```

Comment: But here what is being measured is the creation of the lambda functions. To measure the sorting itself the `timeit` calls should be `timeit(f1())` and `timeit(f2())`. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @dojuba `timeit.timeit` calls its argument if it is not a string.

Comment: yeah, but who writes anything in python that needs to be fast

Answer (score 22):

Leaving aside the speed issue, which is often based on where you make the itemgetter or lambda function, I personally find that `itemgetter` is really nice for getting multiple items at once: for example, `itemgetter(0, 4, 3, 9, 19, 20)` will create a function that returns a tuple of the items at the specified indices of the listlike object passed to it. To do that with a lambda, you'd need `lambda x:x[0], x[4], x[3], x[9], x[19], x[20]`, which is a lot clunkier. (And then some packages such as `numpy` have advanced indexing, which works a lot like `itemgetter()` except built in to normal bracket notation.)

Comment: +1 excellent point about multiple entries, certainly itemgetter is the winner there.