# Sorting a list of tuples in python according to an element index

Tags: python, list, sorting

How can I sort a list of tuples according to the int in a certain position? (without a for loop)

eg. Sorting `l = [(1,5,2),(7,1,4),(1,6,3)]` according to the third element in each tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`list.sort`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort), its key function, and [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> l = [(1,5,2),(7,1,4),(1,6,3)]
>>> l.sort(key=itemgetter(2))
>>> l
[(1, 5, 2), (1, 6, 3), (7, 1, 4)]
>>>
```

---

You could also use a [lambda function](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) instead of `operator.itemgetter`:

```
>>> l = [(1,5,2),(7,1,4),(1,6,3)]
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])
>>> l
[(1, 5, 2), (1, 6, 3), (7, 1, 4)]
>>>
```

However, the latter is [generally faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17243726/2555451).

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the key by which to sort a list using the [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) builtin:

```
>>> mylist = sorted([(1,5,2),(7,1,4),(1,6,3)], key = lambda t: t[2])
>>> mylist
[(1, 5, 2), (1, 6, 3), (7, 1, 4)]
>>>
```