# Converting nucleotides to the corresponding DNA sequence

Tags: python, list, function, bioinformatics

I´m working on an assignment in python. I have to find a function or a program that converts this list to the corresponding DNA sequence.

```
bases_list = ['Adenosine', 'Guanine', 'Thymine', 'Cytosine', 'Thymine', 'Adenosine', 'Guanine', 'Cytosine', 'Thymine', 'Adenosine', 'Guanine']

print(dna)

AGTCTAGCTAG  #the output
```

I think maybe I can make a definition function to convert those bases to corresponding letters. How can I do that? Any ideas?

PS: I began to learn python very recently, so I hope you guys can help me :)

Comment: print("".join([x[0] for x in bases_list]))

Comment: But I have to print as print(dna), which means that I have to find a function that I should call as "dna". Do you think I have to write a def function?

Comment: I think you need to learn the basics of Python programming first.

Comment: "...an assignment to **find** a function..." ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes a few! as you begin not a long time ago, let do something simple:

```
bases_list = ['Adenosine', 'Guanine', 'Thymine', 'Cytosine', 'Thymine', 'Adenosine', 'Guanine', 'Cytosine', 'Thymine', 'Adenosine', 'Guanine']

dna = "" # You begin with the dna empty

for sequence in bases_list: # you go throw every chain
  dna += sequence[0] # you add the first letter with the op [0] of lists

print(dna) # finally print
```

You can read about the basis of loop here https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Answer (score 2):

Most succinct:

```
print("".join([x[0] for x in bases_list]))

dna = "".join(x[0] for x in bases_list])
print(dna)
```

otherwise:

```
dna = ""
for base in bases_list:
    dna += base[0] . # get 1st letter from base
print(dna)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's use string indexing and `join`:

```
dna = ''.join(i[0] for i in bases_list)
print(dna)
```

Output:

```
AGTCTAGCTAG
```

Comment: What does the join syntax actually? I never saw that in our course :)

Comment: @berr Join takes each element from an iterable and concatenates them into one string with or with a separator. [See docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Answer (score 2):

How about a `map`?

```
In [276]: ''.join(map(lambda x: x[0], bases_list))
Out[276]: 'AGTCTAGCTAG'
```

`str.join` is used to take a list (or any iterable) of strings and join them together. `map` applies the same function to every element in an iterable.

Quick note. I ran this code on a terminal, but if you're running this in a script, don't forget to *assign* the result back to another variable.

```
seq = ''.join(map(lambda x: x[0], bases_list))
print(seq)
```

Comment: Nice one, for advanced users ;) I'm thinking another simple way but I don't came with Ideas, do you have any else?

Comment: @DamianLattenero No, I believe every simple option has been discussed in these answers. Anything else will need some thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I thought I would add the `itemgetter` https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter solution.

In this case, it gets the character in index `(0)` of every element in `bases_list`. It is said to be slightly faster and cleaner than `lambda` [operator.itemgetter or lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243620/operator-itemgetter-or-lambda)

```
from operator import itemgetter

bases_list = ['Adenosine', 'Guanine', 'Thymine', 'Cytosine', 'Thymine',
              'Adenosine', 'Guanine', 'Cytosine', 'Thymine', 'Adenosine', 'Guanine']
dna = "".join((map(itemgetter(0),bases_list)))

print (dna)
```

result:

```
AGTCTAGCTAG
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function that converts the base name to its corresponding letter, you are lucky here, because it is simply the first letter of the base name.

Taking the first letter of a string is easily done by "indexing". For instance:

```
base = "Adenosine"
letter = base[0]
# letter should now be "A"
```

In a simple case like this, one would probably not bother defining a specific function, but it is possible and may look as follows:

```
def base2letter(base):
    """This function converts the name of a base into the corresponding letter."""
    return base[0]
```

Now you can apply the function to every base name in your list. The usual way to do this in python is by using a "list comprehension":

```
letters_list = [base2letter(base) for base in bases_list]
```

What you have now is the list of the letters: `["A", "G", "T", "C", "T", "A", "G", "C", "T", "A", "G"]`

The next step is to join them together into a string. An efficient way to do this is to use the `join` method that is defined for strings. It sticks the string between the successive elements it is given: `"_".join(["A", "B", "C"])` will result in `"A_B_C"`. Here you want to put the letters together with nothing between them, so you have to use the empty string:

```
dna = "".join(letters_list)
```

Note that progressively building the string in a for loop by concatenating new letters one by one to the current state of the string is possible (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47036161/1878788). This may be expected of you if python is just used to give you a general idea of how programming languages using an "imperative" style work. However, it is not efficient in python, that is why many answers did not use this technique.