# Python: Why return-type of itemgetter is not consistent

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python `itemgetter` doesn't return tuples of length 0 or 1. 
For example:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def get_something(keys):
    d = {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    }
    return itemgetter(*keys)(d)

print(type(get_something(["a", "b"])))
# <class 'tuple'>
print(type(get_something(["a"])))
# <class 'int'>
print(type(get_something([])))
# TypeError: itemgetter expected 1 arguments, got 0
```

- Is there any good reason that the `itemgetter` is written this way?  And not `(1,)` for the second last `()` and for the last?
- Is there some other built-in option if I always want to return a tuple/list given the keys?

Comment: what do your `print`s actually `return`?

Comment: I added it above

Comment: `itemgetter` is a pretty trivial helper function. If the way it works doesn't suit you, you should write your own that works the way you want. FWIW I agree with you about inconsistent return types.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser  Yes, but for me it looks like an obvious design flaw but still I realise that people who created Python are 100x smarter than me. So I am trying to understand what am I missing here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there some other built-in option if I always want to return a
>   tuple/list given the keys?

just use a comprehension:

```
[d[k] for k in keys]
```

In context:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def get_something(keys):
    d = {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    }
    return [d[k] for k in keys]

print(get_something(["a", "b"]))
#[1, 2]
print(get_something(["a"]))
#[1]
print(get_something([]))
#[]
```

Comment: If already going down that path, consider using `.get` to avoid potential `KeyError`.

Comment: @DeepSpace Yah could do or `[d[k] for k in keys if k in d]`, depends what they want in such circmumstances

Comment: Ok. So why do we have `itemgetter` built-in at all?  I mean this is a good way to do it but hard for me to image a situation where I would use the actual `itemgetter` for anything.

Comment: @Pekka `itemgetter` is suitable for some tasks, like sorting based on the 2nd item `sorted([('a', 2), ('b', 1)], key=itemgetter(1))`

Comment: @Chris_Rands but `key=lambda x: x[1]` is just as short. And the sorting would work even though we would return a tuple for one key itemgetter. Well maybe this is too trivial discussion but I am still not 100% convinced :|

Comment: @Pekka Using `lambda` works, but it is less performant (slower) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243620/operator-itemgetter-or-lambda

Comment: @Chris_Rands I see. And indeed sorting items is faster than tuples of one item so in that case for performance this behaviour makes sense.

Comment: itemgetter has different implementation from list-comprehension. Python3.8 has better itemgetter for performance.

Answer (score 3):

Part of your confusion comes from the fact that your `get_something()` func takes a single argument (expected to be an iterable) and unpacks it when passing it to `itemgetter()`. This results in the return value of `get_something()` not being "symetric" with it's arguments.

If you defined `get_something()` to use varargs instead (as `itemgetter()` does) :

```
def get_something(*keys):
    d = {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    }
    return itemgetter(*keys)(d)
```

the return values would be more consistant with the arguments, ie:

```
# ask for 3 keys, get 3 values:
>>> get_something("a", "b", "c")
(1, 2, 3)

# ask for 2 keys, get 2 values:
>>> get_something("a", "b")
(1, 2)

# ask for one key, get 1 value
>>> get_something("a")
1

# all of this with tuple unpacking in mind:

a, b = get_something("a", "b")
a = get_something("a")
```

Now the point is that few people would bother using `itemgetter()` to implement your `get_something` function - `itemgetter` has mainly been designed to be used as a callback for `sorted()` and like functions / methods (where it's current behaviour makes sense), and `get_something` would more canonically be implemented with a list expression ie:

```
def get_something(keys):
    d = {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    }
    return [d[k] for k in keys]
```

which would take an iterable and return a (possibly empty) list.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is documented in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) (emphasis is mine):

> Return a callable object that fetches item from its **operand using the
>   operand’s `__getitem__()` method. If multiple items are specified,
>   returns a tuple of lookup values**

`itemgetter` does not decide the return type, it is the operand's `__getitem__()` method.

> Wouldn't it be easier/better

"better" is subjective. You can always wrap `itemgetter`:

```
def get_something(keys):
    def my_itemgetter():
        r = itemgetter(*keys)(d)
        return (r,) if type(r) is not tuple else r

    d = {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    }

    return my_itemgetter()
```

Comment: Ok maybe that part of the question is subjective, but I meant better for everybody. I will change the question to be more objective :)