# Python sorting two lists together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I'm having some problems with my code below. I have my two lists names and scores. These lists, correspond with each other as seen below. My goal is to print out the first three greatest items in both lists. I've attempted to sort them together from greatest to least and then print out the first three items, but I'm getting some unbounderror. Any thoughts? Thanks.

```
names = ['Xander', 'Spec', 'Meng', 'Sparc', 'Jones', 'Nick', 'Link']
scores = [120, 450, 300, 200, 66, 183, 80]

scores, names = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(scores, names))))
print(names[:3] + " " + scores[:3])
```

Example Output:

```
Spec 450
Meng 300
Sparc 200
```

Comment: What's the exact error? There shouldn't be anything unbound here.

Comment: You have not included the error. You are trying to concatenate str with list which is not possible. Try:`" ".join(map(str,scores[:3])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only issue with your code is the print part (and you'd have to reverse the sort):

```
scores, names = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(scores, names), reverse=True)))

for name, score, _i in zip(scores, names, range(3)):
    print(name, score)

# 450 Spec
# 300 Meng
# 200 Sparc
```

---

i'd suggest you use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

names = ['Xander', 'Spec', 'Meng', 'Sparc', 'Jones', 'Nick', 'Link']
scores = [120, 450, 300, 200, 66, 183, 80]

counter = Counter({name: score for name, score in zip(names, scores)})
print(counter.most_common(3))
# [('Spec', 450), ('Meng', 300), ('Sparc', 200)]
```

you could then format the result the way you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `heapq.nlargest`:

```
from heapq import nlargest
for score, name in nlargest(3, zip(scores, names)):
    print(name, score)
```

This outputs:

```
Spec 450
Meng 300
Sparc 200
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is in the print part:

```
for i in range(3):
    print(names[i], scores[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your print in the last line is wrong. you can not concatenate `list` object with `str` like that. do this instead:

```
scores, names = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(scores, names), reverse=True)))

for i in range(3):
    print(names[i], scores[i])
```

NOTE: `reverse=True` is for sort the lists in reverse order (DESC).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to concatenate two lists and a string within your print statement. Daniel Möller's answer is correct. Also you may need to pass `True` to the `reverse=` keyword argument, otherwise you'll get the smallest three:

```
names = ['Xander', 'Spec', 'Meng', 'Sparc', 'Jones', 'Nick', 'Link']
scores = [120, 450, 300, 200, 66, 183, 80]

scores, names = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(scores, names), reverse=True)))

for i in range(3):
    print(names[i], scores[i]) 

Spec 450
Meng 300
Sparc 200
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

```
names = ['Xander', 'Spec', 'Meng', 'Sparc', 'Jones', 'Nick', 'Link']
scores = [120, 450, 300, 200, 66, 183, 80]
data = list(zip(names, scores))
print(data)
# output [('Xander', 120), ('Spec', 450), ('Meng', 300), ('Sparc', 200), ('Jones', 66), ('Nick', 183), ('Link', 80)]
data.sort(key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
print(data)
# output [('Spec', 450), ('Meng', 300), ('Sparc', 200), ('Nick', 183), ('Xander', 120), ('Link', 80), ('Jones', 66)]


for name, score in data:
    print(name,score,sep='\t')

""" output 
Spec    450
Meng    300
Sparc   200
Nick    183
Xander  120
Link    80
Jones   66
"""
```

as changes suggested,  this can be done in a more elegant way like this.

```
names = ['Xander', 'Spec', 'Meng', 'Sparc', 'Jones', 'Nick', 'Link']
scores = [120, 450, 300, 200, 66, 183, 80]
data = list(zip(scores, names))
print(data)
# output [(120, 'Xander'), (450, 'Spec'), (300, 'Meng'), (200, 'Sparc'), (66, 'Jones'), (183, 'Nick'), (80, 'Link')]
data.sort(reverse=True)
print(data)
# output [(450, 'Spec'), (300, 'Meng'), (200, 'Sparc'), (183, 'Nick'), (120, 'Xander'), (80, 'Link'), (66, 'Jones')]

for score, name in data:
    print(name,score,sep='\t')

""" output 
Spec    450
Meng    300
Sparc   200
Nick    183
Xander  120
Link    80
Jones   66
"""
```

using itemgetter as suggested by  @Jab

```
names = ['Xander', 'Spec', 'Meng', 'Sparc', 'Jones', 'Nick', 'Link']
scores = [120, 450, 300, 200, 66, 183, 80]
data = list(zip(names, scores))
print(data)
# output [('Xander', 120), ('Spec', 450), ('Meng', 300), ('Sparc', 200), ('Jones', 66), ('Nick', 183), ('Link', 80)]
from operator import itemgetter
data.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print(data)
# output [('Spec', 450), ('Meng', 300), ('Sparc', 200), ('Nick', 183), ('Xander', 120), ('Link', 80), ('Jones', 66)]


for name, score in data:
    print(name,score,sep='\t')

""" output 
Spec    450
Meng    300
Sparc   200
Nick    183
Xander  120
Link    80
Jones   66
"""
```

Comment: You can change the order inside the `zip` to (scores,names) and then you need not to pass the key argument in `sort`. Nothing fancy but will be much more elegant

Comment: Also `operator.itemgetter(1)` is more prefered than `lambda x: x[1]` It's more efficient and reads better

Comment: @mad_ yeah that was helpful.

Comment: @Jab operator.itemgetter(1) is more readable(cann't say about efficiency), i don't want to include extra library , that is why i stick with lambda approach.

Comment: `operator` is a builtin library and it is more efficient and powerful. See: [operator.itemgetter or lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243620/operator-itemgetter-or-lambda/17243726)

Comment: @Jab yeah, you are right, didn't know this performance difference, thanks for suggesting.

Comment: Not that it's a huge difference, but it's good to get in the habit of using something more readable and better especially when it's included as a builtin. `lambda` may be faster/easier to type in but readability counts. And the performace impact will be there when it's needed

Comment: @Jab yeah readability counts, if u see the solution by jdharo  [operator.itemgetter or lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243620/operator-itemgetter-or-lambda/17243726) then I think it's great performance gap.

Answer (score 0):

You can zip and sort the data using `operator.itemgetter` then print the data like so:

```
from operator import itemgetter

names = ['Xander', 'Spec', 'Meng', 'Sparc', 'Jones', 'Nick', 'Link']
scores = [120, 450, 300, 200, 66, 183, 80]

data = sorted(zip(names, scores), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
for name, score in data[:3]:
    print(f"{name}: {score}")
```

This outputs:

```
Spec: 450
Meng: 300
Sparc: 200
```

Answer (score 0):

If `names` are unique I suggest usage of `dict`, following way:

```
names = ['Xander', 'Spec', 'Meng', 'Sparc', 'Jones', 'Nick', 'Link']
scores = [120, 450, 300, 200, 66, 183, 80]
high = sorted([i for i in d.items()],key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)[:3]
for i in high:
    print(i[0],i[1])
```

Output:

```
Spec 450
Meng 300
Sparc 200
```

`key` in `sorted` is used to point that it should sort by value (2nd one, as indexing start at 0) and `reverse` is meaning desceding order.