# Sorting a tuple of key, value pairs

Tags: python

I've got the following tuple of key, value pairs.

```
mytuple = (('2200', '10:00 PM'), ('2230', '10:30 PM'), ('2300', '11:00 PM'), ('2330', '11:30 PM'), ('0', '12:00 AM'), ('30', '12:30 AM'))
```

How would I sort this based on the key (i.e. time in 24 hour format)?

Comment: Help here: https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-sort-a-list-tuple-or-object-with-sorted-in-python/

Comment: post your attempts code to sort

Comment: `sorted(mytuple, key=lambda tpl: int(tpl[0]))`

Comment: How about... `sorted(mytuple)`. That would work if your keys really were in 24-hour format, but `'0'` and `'30'` are not in 24-hour format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list/tuple of lists/tuples by the element at a given index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-a-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples-by-the-element-at-a-given-index)

Answer (score 0):

```py
print(sorted(mytuple, key=lambda x: int(x[0])))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that gives better performance:

```
import operator

print(sorted(mytuple, key=operator.itemgetter(0)))
```

For performance comparison, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17243726/13991219)