# How to format this dictionary in a specific way

Tags: python, formatting

I'm making a program that counts the occurrences of each string in a file so I wrote this

```
f = open('strings.txt', 'r')
content = f.read()
mystr = list(content)
data = {k: mystr.count(k) for k in mystr}
print(data)
```

How do I print the output in a format like this for example

```
 whitespace = 286
 "e" = 204
 "n" = 164
 "i" = 156
 "a" = 147
```

Comment: You are reimplementing [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). `data = Counter(f.read())` could replace all existing code. Also you colud use [`Counter.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common): `print(*(f'"{k}" = {v}' for k, v in data.most_common()), sep="\n")`

Comment: Another way is str = json.dumps(data, indent=0,separators=('', ':' ))
print(str[2:-2])

Answer (score 0):

use [`python string format`](https://pyformat.info/):

```
for key, value in data.items():
    print("{}={}".format(key, value))
```

However your solution is not efficient and [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) already solve this problem with an more efficient way:

```
from collections import Counter
words = ['x','y','z','x','x','x','y', 'z']
print(Counter(words))

# Counter({'x': 4, 'y': 2, 'z': 2})
```

for sorting the results you can use `sorted` like this:

```
x = Counter(words)
sorted(x.items(), key=lambda i: i[1])
```

or

```
sorted(x.items(), key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)  # to sort in ascending order
```

Comment: How do I arrange it in descending order based on their count?

Comment: @Gaemon, if you are using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), there's specific method [`Counter.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common). If you *(for some reasons)* use regular dict, you need to apply [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and pass [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to `key` argument: `sorted(data.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)`.

Comment: @Gaemon See my updated answer.

Comment: @MojtabaKamyabi, do not use `lambda` to retrieve element by index, there's [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). At all, don't use method with sorting for `Counter`, there's a specific method for this.

Comment: @OlvinRoght `operator` needs to be imported. anyway what is the drawback of using lambda in this case?

Comment: @MojtabaKamyabi, it's significantly slower. You can make some benchmarks. And what's wrong with imports? It's part of std library, not third party module, you already have it, why not to use it?

Comment: @OlvinRoght yes it seems [you are right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17243726/1033510). I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`[f'{i}={j}' for i,j in data.items()]`

Comment: to print this you'll need to do `print('\n'.join([f'{i}={j}' for i,j in data.items()]))`

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?