# Sorting and Grouping Nested Lists Consists of Class Objects

Tags: python, list, sorting, object, grouping

I have hundreds of text files that i need to parse according to the username and the date. I tried to put useful data in the text files in lists like that:

```
    [
      ['1234245@gmail.com', '34209809' '1434546354', '2016-07-18 00:20:58'], 
      ['abcd@gmail.com', '234534345', '09402380',, '2016-07-18 00:20:03'], 
      ['username@gmail.com', '345315531','1098098098', '2016-07-18 02:40:00'], 
      ['abcd@gmail.com', '345431353', '231200023', '2016-07-18 15:45:49'], 
      ['1234245@gmail.com', '23232424', '234809809', '2016-07-18 20:45:40']
    ]
```

However, I would like to sort them according to the datetime and group by usernames so the output will be like:

```
    [
     ['1234245@gmail.com', '23232424', '234809809', '2016-07-18 20:45:40'],
     ['1234245@gmail.com', '34209809' '1434546354', '2016-07-18 00:20:58'],
     ['abcd@gmail.com', '345431353', '231200023', '2016-07-18 15:45:49'],
     ['abcd@gmail.com', '234534345', '09402380',, '2016-07-18 00:20:03'],
     ['username@gmail.com', '345315531','1098098098', '2016-07-18 02:40:00']
    ]
```

Here is my code:

```
    import glob
    from operator import itemgetter
    from itertools import groupby
    def read_large_file(filename):
        matrix=[]
        global username
        username=[]
        for myfile in glob.glob(filename):
            infile = open(myfile, "r")
            for row in infile:
                row=row.strip()
                array=row.split(';') 
                username.append(array[9])
                matrix.append(cdr(array[9],array[17],array[18],array[8]))

        return matrix


    class cdr(object):               
        def__init__(self,username,total_seconds_since_start,download_bytes,date_time):
            self.username=username
            self.total_seconds_since_start=total_seconds_since_start
            self.download_bytes=download_bytes
            self.date_time=date_time


    def GroupByUsername(matrix):
        new_matrix=[]
        new_matrix=groupby(matrix, itemgetter(0))
        return new_matrix

    matrix=read_large_file('C:\Users\ceren\.spyder2/test/*')
    matrix_new=GroupByUsername(matrix)
```

I tried to use the solution in this link : [Sorting and Grouping Nested Lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409370/sorting-and-grouping-nested-lists-in-python) however i've got these errors:

```
   'cdr' object does not support indexing
   'cdr' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably just use the simple Python built-in sort.

```
sorted_list = sorted(data, key=lambda user_info: (user_info[0], user_info[3]))
```

The lambda key tells Python how to sort the list (ascending). For each entry in `data`, `user_info` will be the list of 4 attributes. So, `user_info[0]` will be the email, and `user_info[3]` will be the datetime.

Comment: Thank youu, i tried however i got this error:    TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot the `key=`. I've fixed it - give it a try :)

Comment: Still have this: TypeError: 'cdr' object does not support indexing , i think python does not let me to put class objects in list indexes.

Comment: If you want to replicate exactly the output you're going to want something like `sorted(sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True), key=lambda x:x[0])` since Timsort is stable.

Comment: The solution I gave will sort the nested list you provided. To sort a list of cdr objects, you will want: `sorted_list = sorted(cdr_list, key=lambda cdr: (cdr.username, cdr.date_time))`

Comment: @CerenH of course python lets you put objects in lists. EVERYTHING is an object in Python. The issue is you are trying to *index your object* and you haven't implemented that functionality in your class. Indeed, I'm not sure what use your class is suppose to have here since there are no methods other than `__init__`